# QuickBooks API V3 Get Accounts by types, sub types and classification

Tags: java, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am using following query to get Account by Type but I get exception:

```
String query1 = select($(account)).where($(account.getAccountType()).eq(AccountTypeEnum.EXPENSE)).generate();

FMSException Message: ERROR CODE:10000, ERROR MESSAGE:An application error has occurred while processing your request, ERROR DETAIL:System Failure Error: Services V3 Query Value for Account.AccountType must be a valid enumeration value
```

How to get Accounts by Classification, Type and SubTypes ? For eg. I would like to have all the accounts associated with Expense Classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the enum value  in the query.

Ex - `SELECT * FROM Account WHERE AccountType = 'Expense'`

Thanks